# c++ set uninitialized long to something that breaks if called

Tags: c++

I spent quite a bit of time debugging because I had a call to an initialized long from a base class that was not set to its proper value, yet, so returned 0. The base class this class derives from is pretty long and has many members with very similar names and setters, so I set a different variable, accidentally. I am fairly new to c++, so I am not sure what a good practice here is.

Is there a way to initialize variables to values that break when called, so that it s easy to spot where mistakes like mine were made (sort of like setting it to the equivalent of setting a pointer to nullptr).

Or is there a better way of making certain that a initialized variable that is a member in a base class will be set before it can be used?

Comment: You could make a habit of initializing all variables by including an initializer in the class definition

Comment: Most of compiler will warn you if you didn't initialize value